# Trying to install Windows 7 PE Lite on KVM Qemu but it goes straight to: "Press esc in 4 sec to skip startup.nsh or any other key to continue."

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am trying to install a Windows VM on Qemu in ubuntu using Virt Manager, but it gives me the below screen:

[image]

And when I type exit, it will take me to the below screen:

[image]

Please suggest a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post this for others who are facing this issue.

Finally find the solution for this.

Try try and try again.

in the beginning choose the architecture as x86 and then simply choose the IDE CDROM as boot order and save the settings.

Begin Installation and there you go.